# purrr::map and R pipe

Tags: r

this code works with the old pipe

```
df |>
group_split(group_lab) %>%
set_names(map_chr(.,~.x$group_lab[1]))
```

But I want it work with the new pipe. Any suggestions?

The code works with the new pipe.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.

Answer (score 3):

The new pipe flat out *does not support* this usage of the placeholder.

The closest you can get is with an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression), i.e.:

```
df |>
  group_split(group_lab) |>
  {\(.) set_names(map_chr(., ~.x$group_lab[1]))}()
```

… not very readable.

But alternatively you can unnest your `set_names()` call:

```
df |>
  group_split(group_lab) |>
  map_chr(~.x$group_lab[1]) |>
  set_names()
```

Answer (score 1):

That operation is not very pretty with pipes, but you could easily create a helper function to clean it up

```
set_names_with <- function(x, fn) {
  set_names(x, map_chr(x, fn))
}
```

For example

```
df <- data.frame(
  a= 1:10,
  group_lab = rep(c("A","B"), each=5)
)


df |>
  group_split(group_lab) |> 
  set_names_with(~.x$group_lab[1])
```

We can pass any function that will take each of the subsets and return a single length character vector name.